# Why is the filter the_title not working when the_content is working fine?

Tags: wordpress

Function and filter to display a player post titles:

```
function wpb_after_post_content($content){

if (is_single()) {
    $id=get_the_ID();
    $post_meta=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'enclosure', TRUE);
    $mp3=explode('.mp3',$post_meta);
    $title=get_the_title();
    if(count($mp3)>1)
    {
        $player = '<div class="post_player">' . do_shortcode('[fap_track url="'.trim($mp3[0]).'.mp3" title=url="'.$title.'" share="" cover="" meta="" layout="list" enqueue=no auto_enqueue=yes]')."</div>";
        $content=$player.$content;
    }
}
    if (is_single()) {
    $id=get_the_ID();
    $post_meta=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'enclosure', TRUE);
    $mp3=explode('.mp3',$post_meta);
    $title=get_the_title();
    if(count($mp3)>1)
    {
        $player = '<div class="zoomsounds_player">'. do_shortcode('[zoomsounds_player source="'.trim($mp3[0]).'.mp3" play_in_footer_player="on" config="default" artistname="'.get_post_meta($id, 'arxiu_de_so', true).'" config="" ]');

            /**if (wp_is_mobile())*/ {
                if(get_post_meta($id, 'arxiu_de_so', true)!=""){
                   /** $player .= " <p id='arxiu_so'> Arxiu de so: ".get_post_meta($id, 'arxiu_de_so', true)."</p>";*/
                    /**$player .= '<span id="arxiuVal" style="opacity:1"> '.get_post_meta($id, 'arxiu_de_so', true).'</span>';*/ 
                }
            }
        $player .="</div>";
        $content=$player.$content;
    }
}
    return $content;
}

add_filter( "the_content", "wpb_after_post_content" );
```

The above code works fine with `the_content` filter and displays the player below the featured image. However, when I use this function with the `the_title` filter, the page doesn't load at all. The reason I want to use `the_title` is because I want the player to display above the featured image but below the post title.

Screenshot:-
[image]

This screenshot is to show that with `the_content` the player displays however it displays below post image.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look as below:

1. If you want to use the_title(), then you no need to pass the post_id in the the_title(), we have some params for the_title() if you want to add them like as below:

   $before
   (string) (Optional) Markup to prepend to the title.

   Default value: ''

   $after
   (string) (Optional) Markup to append to the title.

   Default value: ''

   $echo
   (bool) (Optional) Whether to echo or return the title. Default true for the echo.

   Default value: true
2. If you want to use get_the_title(), then you must need to pass post_id inside the get_the_title($postId);
3. According to your code snippet, you must update your code with as below for get_the_title():

```js
<?php
 function wpb_after_post_content($content){
  if (is_single()) {
      $id=get_the_ID();
      $post_meta=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'enclosure', TRUE);
      $mp3=explode('.mp3',$post_meta);
      $title=get_the_title($id);
      if(count($mp3)>1) {
             $player = '<div class="post_player">' . do_shortcode('[fap_track url="'.trim($mp3[0]).'.mp3" title=url="'.$title.'" share="" cover="" meta="" layout="list" enqueue=no auto_enqueue=yes]')."</div>";
    $content=$player.$content;
      }
  }
     return $content;
 }
 add_filter( "the_content", "wpb_after_post_content" );
?>
```

4. And for the the_title(), you should update your code with as below:

```js
<?php
 function wpb_after_post_content($content){
  if (is_single()) {
      $id=get_the_ID();
      $post_meta=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'enclosure', TRUE);
      $mp3=explode('.mp3',$post_meta);
      $title=get_the_title();
      if(count($mp3)>1)
      {
          $player = '<div class="post_player">' . do_shortcode('[fap_track url="'.trim($mp3[0]).'.mp3" title=url="'.the_title().'" share="" cover="" meta="" layout="list" enqueue=no auto_enqueue=yes]')."</div>";
          $content=$player.$content;
      }
  }

     return $content;
 }
 add_filter( "the_content", "wpb_after_post_content" );
?>
```

NOTE: You have not declared the title parameter in the zoomsounds_player shortcode so please pass and update accordingly.

I hope it would help you out.